# Simple program convert int16_t array to uint16_t

Tags: c, arrays, types, uint16

I have used the WinFilter Program to compute the FIR filter on C code but I got a issue:

The program only provide the 16 bits signed array and i need to that this vector be a unsigned int. So i am looking for a simple solution to relocated the array values to the next "values".

```
int16_t FIRCoef[Ntap] = {
    -1029,
    -1560,
    -1188,
        0,
     1405,
     2186,
     1718,
        0,
    -2210,
    -3647,
    -3095,
        0,
     5160,
    10947,
    15482,
    17197,
    15482,
    10947,
     5160,
        0,
    -3095,
    -3647,
    -2210,
        0,
     1718,
     2186,
     1405,
        0,
    -1188,
    -1560,
    -1029,
        0
};
```

---

```
uint16_t fir(uint16_t NewSample) {
    static uint16_t x[Ntap]; //input samples
    uint32_t y=0;            //output sample
    int n;

    //shift the old samples
    for(n=Ntap-1; n>0; n--)
       x[n] = x[n-1];

    //Calculate the new output
    x[0] = NewSample;
    for(n=0; n<Ntap; n++)
        y += FIRCoef[n] * x[n]; // calculo da convolucao na amostra
                                // Calculation of the convolution in the sample    
    return y / DCgain;
}
```

I think that one solution should be like this:

```
uint16_t--------int16_t---------index
0               -32767            1
1               -32766            2
2               -32765            3
...              ...             ...
65535            32767            65535
```

any hint?

Comment: What about -32768, which is representable as an `int16_t`?  Shouldn't that be the value that maps to 0?  And if the "index" values start at 1 and run to 65535, but the corresponding `uint16_t` values start at 0 and run to 65535, then which `uint16_t` value is skipped?

Comment: `return y / DCgain;` this looks wrong.  I'd expect `int32_t iy=0; ... return iy / DCgain;`

Comment: Consider the off-by-one of the "one solution should be like this:  `0...65535` is an even to an odd and `-32767 ... 32767` is an odd to an odd.  That is mapping 65,536 `uint16_t` into 65,535 `int16_t`.  Something is missing.

Comment: Is the `fir()` function essential to the question?  I don't see what aspect of it would affect the content of an answer.

Comment: the fir() function has already fixed. In fact i dont actually need the 32 bits output value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value range for an `int16_t` is -32768 to 32767.  Your question is unclear on this point, but it seems like you want simply to shift these values into the range of a `uint16_t`, 0 to 65535.  That's reasonable, as the number of representable values for the two types is the same; it would be accomplished by adding the inverse of the minimum possible value of an `int16_t` to the input.

Of course, the Devil is in the details.  When signed addition overflows, undefined behavior results.  When an out-of-range value is converted to a signed integer type, the result is implementation defined, and can be an (implementation-defined) exception.  It is desirable to avoid implementation-defined behavior and essential to avoid undefined behavior; that can be done in this case with just a little care:

```
uint16_t convert(int16_t in) {
    return (uint16_t) 32768 + (uint16_t) in;
}
```

That reliably does the right thing on any conforming system that provides the `uint16_t` and `int16_t` types in the first place, because the conversion and the addition operate modulo one plus the maximum value of a `uint16_t`.  The negative input values are converted to unsigned values in the upper half of the range of `uint16_t`, and the addition then rotates all the values, bringing those from the upper half of the range around to the lower half.

As for doing it to a whole array, if you want to rely only on well-defined C behavior (i.e. if you want a solution that strictly conforms to the standard) then you'll need to make a copy of the data.  You could use a function such as the above to populate the copy.

Comment: Upvoted, but doesn't this shift the values into the range [1, 65535]?

Comment: No, @DavidBowling, why would it?  -32768 converts to 0; +32767 converts to 65535; everything else converts 1:1 onto the numbers between.

Comment: But isn't `INT_MIN` -32767?

Comment: @DavidBowling, `INT_MIN` is implementation defined and irrelevant.  -32767 is the largest it can be, but on many common platforms, even those with 16-bit `int`s, it is smaller (more negative).  `int16_t`, where provided, is a 16-bit, two's complement integer type with no padding bits.  It follows that its minimum value is definitely -32768.  Always.

Comment: There it is.... I was thinking that the largest allowable `INT_MIN`, which is -32767, is the same as the smallest 16 bit signed integer, but now I see that was wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: Signed overflow is undefined not implementation defined.

Comment: tks for your simple solution. idk that signed int range value begin -32768. anyways i cant do upvote cause i newb on stackoverflow.